# Filter one ag-grid based on event from another one

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I want to select one row in my first grid `grid1` and the event function would then filter my other grid `grid2` based on the values found in the selected row. I am using the pure javascript version of the library.

Something like

```
gridOptions:{
    onRowSelected:my_event_filter_func,
    rowData: [...],
    columnDefs:[...]
}
grid1 = new agGrid.Grid(document.querySelector("#the_place"),gridOptions)
```

(`grid2` is defined the same way based on different data and w/o the event function)

where `my_event_filter_func` is

```
my_event_filter_func = function(event) {
    let my_name = event.data.name
    // filter grid2 to show only the rows where the 'name' column matches my_name
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to get data from the selected row(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for the 2 grids is the underlying data for `grid1` so it made my life easier. If that is not the case, you do need to save your base data for `grid2` somewhere so that you can access it when the event gets triggered.

I ended up declaring my 2 grids as global variables and using the function below as event function :

```
var onSelectionChanged = function(event) {

let name = grid1.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[0].name; // we know there is only one
let newRowData = grid1.gridOptions.rowData
    .filter(x => x.name===name)
    .map(x => {
            return {
                'name': x.name
                // other fields...
            }
    })
    // this overwrites grid2 data so need to save original data somewhere.
    grid2.gridOptions.api.setRowData(newRowData);
    grid2.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({force:true});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a line by line answer, and I am assuming that you are able to get your selected rows. But what I can suggest is, first, you create a copy of your the data that is on your grid2.

```
function copyData() {
  rowData = [];
  gridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
  // temp is the copy of your full data in grid2
  temp = [...rowData];
}
```

Next, on your `my_event_filter_func`, you can filter out the rows to be shown on grid2, based on the filtered value from grid1.

```
function my_event_filter_func(event) {
  let my_name = event.data.name

  // get the rows that do not have the matching value
  const rowsToBeRemoved = temp.filter(row => row['name'] !== my_name);

  // remove the rows from grid2 that do not have the matching names
  gridOptions.api.updateRowData({remove: rowsToBeRemoved});

}
```

Comment: Thks for taking the time. yes i ended up doing something like that. WIll post my answer as well.

Comment: Nice! Would love to see your solution too, and see how you implement it. I'm currently doing quite a lot of stuff with ag-grid, thus I am trying to learn from as many ag-grid users as possible. Well, if my code is helpful, would appreciate if you could upvote ;)